# How do I add an Undo Function Within jsPlumb?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsplumb

After deleting the node element I want it to repaint when I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> , basically adding the node element again.

I tried to repaint the node after removing it but had no luck, it didn't work.

```
$(document).on('click','#close',function(el){
      instance.remove($(this).offsetParent());
}); 
$scope.KeyPress = function(e) {
      var evtobj = window.event? event : e
      if (evtobj.keyCode == 90 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
          instance.repaint($(this).offsetParent());

      }
};
document.onkeydown = $scope.KeyPress;
```

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Does the program work with performing other tasks? i.e. Is the problem the key events?

Comment: I am able to trigger the key events i.e. Creating the node connectors and connection all I want is when I remove a node with  instance.remove($(this).offsetParent());       I want to get this node back on ctrl+z